# Alternative for Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, linux, user-interface, cron, scheduler

I need a Task Scheduler for Windows. Unfortunately the builtin scheduler doesn't meet my needs, which are:

- can run tasks every minute/hour
- runs on Linux and Windows
- 32 and 64 bit versions
- GUI interface
- free

Nice to haves:

- supports CRON files
- open source
- status reports of execution times

thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrated to SuperUser? How is it programming related?

Comment: A very good freeware [250 KB] that does this perfectly: [Freebyte Task Scheduler](http://www.freebyte.com/fbtaskscheduler/). I post it as a comment since it's impossible to post an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just some corrections on your claims regarding the Windows Task Scheduler.

> - can run tasks every minute/hour

Every hour:

[image: Run a task every hour]
<sub>(source: [hypftier.de](http://hypftier.de/dump/ts_every_hour.png))</sub>

or minute:

[image: Run a task every minute]
<sub>(source: [hypftier.de](http://hypftier.de/dump/ts_every_minute.png))</sub>

> - runs on Linux and Windows

Ok, you get that probably only with cron. But Windows and Linux are different enough to warrant OS-specific stuff anyway, so why bother burdening Windows users with yet another scheduler? (There are already too many out there as nearly every single application that needs something scheduled includes its own ...)

Same for an arbitrary non-cron scheduler for Linux, though, just for both platforms, then.

> - 32 and 64 bit versions

The Windows Task Scheduler runs as a service, bittiness is kinda a no-issue there as it only starts other processes which couldn't care less about whether their spawner was 32 or 64 bit. However, it's available in 64 and 32 bit.

> - GUI interface

Enough GUI?

[image: GUI]
<sub>(source: [hypftier.de](http://hypftier.de/dump/ts_gui_1.png))</sub>   [image: GUI]
<sub>(source: [hypftier.de](http://hypftier.de/dump/ts_gui_2.png))</sub>   [image: GUI]
<sub>(source: [hypftier.de](http://hypftier.de/dump/ts_gui_3.png))</sub>   [image: GUI]
<sub>(source: [hypftier.de](http://hypftier.de/dump/ts_gui_4.png))</sub>   [image: GUI]
<sub>(source: [hypftier.de](http://hypftier.de/dump/ts_gui_5.png))</sub>

> - free

Included in every Windows installation. Should suffice, I'd say.

Comment: my version on Windows XP looks very different and doesn't include those features, so you must be using a newer version

Comment: Not available on Windows Server 2003

Comment: Indeed, the windows task scheduler for windows server 2003 is a real shame : Many bugs, no proper log file, no notifications by email :
I cannot even understand how people can use this crap for production applications.

Comment: Try using a windows forms application with an Active X control in windows task scheduler... Like a webbrowser control e.g. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: While Windows Task Scheduler does a lot, it doesn't work for everyone and there are good reasons to search for an alternative. A deal-breaker with my team is you cannot manage or view tasks on a remote machine unless either you own the task or you are an admin on the remote machine.

Comment: Contrary to what's said above and even implied by the images, Windows Task Scheduler can't actually schedule tasks every minute or even every hour. The task can kick off at a given time of day and then be set to repeat every x units of time for y units of time. If you break the execution chain during a day for instance, the task repetition won't begin again until the next day. It's difficult to express that difference concisely, and one may even need to experiment with it to understand that difference. It's a field away from tools like cron.

Answer (score 4):

Cron supports Cron files, so does Cron for Windows!

http://cronw.sourceforge.net/

Comment: appears to require perl.

Answer (score 2):

> Windows only: Freeware utility Z-Cron replaces the Windows task scheduler with a more robust, cron-like alternative (but with a graphical interface). Z-Cron ships with a long set of useful actions you can automate, like sending an email, copying a folder, deleting files, emptying the trash, and way more, which makes writing batch files to do these things for you effectively obsolete. Z-Cron is a free download for Windows only.

[Z-Cron](http://www.z-cron.com/scheduler.html)

Answer (score 2):

It amazes me how everyone keeps yelling "Alternatives!" on windows programs/functions even when they don't know the first things about using them. The task scheduler DOES work in XP/Vista/Seven (on cared-for systems of course, not those infested with malware, errors and resident bloatware), and it does a pretty good job too. For instance hourly scheduling is even available in XP together with lots of other options available through gui as well as batch commands.

Answer (score 1):

We use Automate from www.networkautomation.com . We actually really like it, but we're a version old and the new version is expensive (like $1,800). It has a fantastic feature set - we've not found anything it can't do. But we're looking for something else since it's so expensive.

Answer (score 1):

"Windows only: Freeware utility Z-Cron replaces the Windows task scheduler with a more robust, cron-like alternative (but with a graphical interface)...."

Z-Cron is NOT free!  It is a 14-30 day trial. Here on Earth we call that shareware.  I don't know where that company gets off calling it "freeware."

It looked like a cool program though.

Comment: I think the limited trial refers to server installations, which seems reasonable (http://www.z-cron.com/download.html) It appears that non-commercial desktop use is not limited

Answer (score 1):

[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)

- supports cron-like scheduling (5 * * * *)
- runs arbitrary processes
- has a web-based interface
- free and open-source (MIT)
- written in Java and runs on Linux or Windows
- haven't tested with 64-bit, but Hudson doesn't depend on native libraries so there's a high chance it will just work
- may take up a larger memory footprint than you're used to
- status reports for failed tasks available, with console output
- easy installation

Comment: Hudson is a Continuous Integration system. It would be a kludge to use it in this way, especially since it needs an application server to run on.

Answer (score 1):

Unless Mel wants to use Z-Cron for commercial purposes, he is wrong about the cost.  From the Z-Cron download page:

> The free programs offered here are
>   freeware for personal use, i.e. they
>   can only be used by private
>   individuals free of charge.

I am using Z-Cron to execute a desktop shortcut at the same time each day. Windows 7 task scheduler would not work for the same task. That's a vote for Z-Cron in my book.

Answer (score 0):

JAMS can easily handle this sort of thing - www.JAMSScheduler.com but like Automate, it ain't cheap.  I do know there is a free Developer's Edition that a bunch of our developers use.  We only use the product on one server but I know it cost a decent chunk.

Answer (score -1):

Windows task scheduler is great....... except when it loses its cookies and forgets all the credentials for your tasks.  It has had this issue for years, there have been hotfixes for NT and beyond, but the issue is still there circa Server 2003 R2.  I have no idea if it is finally corrected in newer versions, but it has lasted far too long.

Unacceptable.

Comment: The OP mentioned that he wants something other than Windows builtin Task Scheduler. This post doesn't help.