# Most efficient method to schedule java application to run daily

Tags: java, timer, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a java application which downloads a file from an FTP server and I need it to run daily. I was just wondering what the best method to schedule it to run would be. The options I  am currently considering are the [Windows scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) and [Java timer task](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/CertainAndRepeatTime.shtml).

At the moment I have the windows scheduler pointing at a batch file which runs my program.

If anybody has any knowledge in the area I would appreciate to hear from you!!

Comment: Anything wrong with the Windows Scheduler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015702/alternative-for-windows-task-scheduler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [AT TASKS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565) on windows and [CRON JOBS](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) on unix. These can run your Java program.

You should also take a look at [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) which is a Java-based job scheduling system.

You can also get help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498837/how-to-run-a-task-daily-from-java).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use @Schedule abilities of EJB 3?
If your server is not EJB 3 - capable, use Quartz, Timer and TimerTask classes.