# Sending email to user via MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, netbeans, mysql-workbench

I'm now working with MySQL workbench and NetBeans IDE on Linux Ubuntu, using Java EE to develop a web application.

Now I require to develop a function which allow each user to update their data weekly, and check the data is update weekly.

If data has not been insert or update to MySQL workbench on last day of a week, it will send an email to notify the user to update the data.

1. How can I achieve it?
2. It is require to work with which tools? MySQL Workbench or Netbean IDE?
3. What is the code or any tutorial to guide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways for doing this. I think you want to do schedular task.

The first way is making in `java code`. Using `@WebListener` and `Threads`. It is pure java libraries. Also you can use `Quartz Schedular` but I prefer java's own library.

MyTaskScheduler.class

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class MyTaskScheduler implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new MyRunnable (), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Here you can change timeOut and delay.
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

MyRunnable.class

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Runnable RUN");
    }
}
```

The second way is create SimpleJavaApplication and using operating system's features.

**In Windows**

You can use TaskSchedular: [Windows Task Scheduler using guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015702/alternative-for-windows-task-scheduler)

**In Linux**

You can use CronTab: [CronTab using guide](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/run-cronjob-every-5-five-minutes-hours.html)

You must create task for any timePeriod for running this simpleApplication.

I must note that. I never uses `CronTab`. I found CronTab alternative of `Windows Task Scheduler` in `Google`.

Comment: Thanks for helping a lot, it's working, how if I want to specify the schedule execute every Friday at a specific time period?

Comment: Which way did you use? WebListener or other?

Comment: Directly I don't know how to make this by `ScheduledExecutorService`. But you can set TimeUnit.Hour and in Runnable Thread you can check day and time. It is tricky way.